# Filas de una tabla de PrimeNg con arrays [Angular]

Tags: angular, primeng

tengo la siguiente tabla basada en Prime ng en el html de mi proyecto hecho en Angular 7.0:

```
<p-table [columns]="calendarCols" [value]="tasks" [tableStyle]="{'table-layout':'auto'}" [scrollable]="false">
            <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
                <tr>
                    <th *ngFor="let col of columns" >
                        {{col.header}} <!-- marcadores de las columnas -->
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </ng-template> 
            <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
              <tr>
                <td  *ngFor="let col of columns">
                       {{rowData[col.field]}} <!-- contenido de la tabla -->
                </td>
            </tr> 
          </ng-template>
          </p-table>
```

Donde calendarCols es:

```
   this.calendarCols = [
     { field: 'jueves', header: 'Jueves' },
     { field: 'lunes', header: 'Lunes' },
     { field: 'martes', header: 'Martes' },
     { field: 'miercoles', header: 'Miércoles' },
     { field: 'viernes', header: 'Viernes' }
   ];
```

Y el value que es tasks, que tiene la siguiente interfaz:

```
export interface TableWeek {
    jueves : number[];
    lunes: number[];
    martes : number[];
    miercoles : number[];
    viernes : number[];
}
```

Lo que intento hacer es, que si se tiene que en cada uno de los días anteriores hay un Array como el siguiente

```
{martes: Array(0), jueves: Array(2), lunes: Array(0), viernes: Array(0), miercoles: Array(0)}
```

Se muestren en esa tabla cada valor del array en una fila, dentro de cada día (representan las columnas). Pero con ese código obtengo el siguiente error:

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
    at NgForOf.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.NgForOf.ngDoCheck (common.js:3368)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:22102)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:23363)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:23325)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:23959)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:23919)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (TableBody.html:3)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:23911)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23307)
    at callViewAction (core.js:23548)
```

¿Alguien sabría como debería recorrer las posiciones del value "tasks" en el html para visitar todas las posiciones de cada array, y pintarlo en la tabla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No entiendo bien lo que quieres hacer, usas verbos como "pintar" o la palabra "que" que me han impedido entenderlo bien, supongo que no hablas español de España y yo debo estar cansado.

Pero el error que muestras si lo entiendo. Es porque intentas mostrar un array donde debería haber un único dato (un número o texto). Esta línea es la que provoca el error:

```
{{ rowData[col.field] }}
```

Porque eso devuelve number[] y angular no lo puede "pintar". Para "pintarlo" debes recorrer nuevamente en un bucle el array retornado. Por ejemplo así:

```
<td  *ngFor="let col of columns">
   <div *ngFor="let dato of rowData[col.field]"> 
     {{ dato }}
   </div>
</td>
```

Tendrás que cambiar el código html para que salga a tu gusto obviamente, pero básicamente lo que te digo es que para mostrar el contenido de tasks que es un array (o objeto en este caso) que contiene arrays, necesitas hacer un bucle anidado.

Espero haberme explicado, suerte!